# Border layout inside a border layout

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to place inside my west panel, 3 panels (north,center and south),so i can place items in it. Any help?

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    north_panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        region :'north', 
        height : '10%',
        items : [] 
    });

    west_panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        region :'west', 
        width: '40%',
        items : [] 
    });

    center_panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        region :'center', 
        items : [] 
    });



    viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout : 'border' ,
        renderTo :'document.body',
        items : [north_panel , west_panel , center_panel]
    });

});
```

Comment: Any news about your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the same that you already did. Declare a layout border inside your west panel and add 3 panels inside with "region" config as you like.

```
{
     xtype : 'panel',
     html : 'West Panel',
     region :'west',
     layout : 'border',
     width: 200,
     items :[{
               xtype : 'panel',
               html : 'North Panel 2',
               region :'north'
             }, {
               xtype : 'panel',
               html : 'South Panel',
               region :'south'
             }, {
               xtype : 'panel',
               html : 'Center Panel 2',
               region :'center'
            }]
}
```

Here is a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Xpe9V/1612/

Hope it helped :)